# How to force GTK window to stay at a certain width, even when widgets try to expand?

Tags: python, pygtk

How do I force a GTK window object to stay the same size, even when a table inside of it tries to expand?

I've tried using gtk.SHRINK when attaching children to the table, but the TextViews within the table still keep expanding to way beyond an acceptable width and expanding the window along with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the size [manually](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--resize)

pyGtk window docs:
http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried using window.resize(), but that didn't work originally.  

In the end, window.set_size_request() worked out nicely. :)

Comment: The links don't work anymore. Please always copy and paste the important parts into the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Text views won't expand if you pack them into a `gtk.ScrolledWindow`.  This is not what you directly asked, but I believe should solve your problem in a better way.

Comment: This would probably work too, but I don't want the window to be scrollable.  Thanks, though.